# How to combine multiple $http calls into one big array that will be used to build a table using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am looking for help on how to combine multiple $http json calls into one big array using angular that will be used to build a table using ng-repeat. Please see the link below for more information.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zh5FkqU6j7IWmj2Rj9EP?p=preview)

Thank you for your help!

```
<div class container>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
            <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' data-day="20160908">
                <tr class='days'>
                    <th>Time (ET)</th>
                    <th>Room One</th>
                    <th>Room Two</th>
                    <th>Room Three</th>
                    <th>Room Four</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="company in allCompanies">
                    <td>{{company.start_formatted}} - {{company.end_formatted}}</td>
                    <td>{{company.company}}</td> <!--this should be roomOne json -->
                    <td>{{company.company}}</td> <!--this should be roomTwo json -->
                    <td>{{company.company}}</td> <!--this should be roomThree json -->
                    <td>{{company.company}}</td> <!--this should be roomFour json -->
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var eventDate = $('table').data('day'); //grabing the date from the table


  $scope.allCompanies = []; // new array that will store all json
  console.log($scope.allCompanies);


  $scope.getJsonOne = $http.get('roomOne.json', {
    cache: false
  });
  $scope.getJsonTwo = $http.get('roomTwo.json', {
    cache: false
  });
  $scope.getJsonThree = $http.get('roomThree.json', {
    cache: false
  });
  $scope.getJsonFour = $http.get('roomFour.json', {
    cache: false
  });


  $q.all([$scope.getJsonOne, $scope.getJsonTwo, $scope.getJsonThree, $scope.getJsonFour]).then(function(values) {
    $scope.results = values;


    angular.forEach($scope.results, function(value, index) {
      $scope.dateOne = value.data;
    });


    var date = eventDate;
    console.log(date);


    if (typeof $scope.dateOne[date] !== 'undefined') {
      var i, start, end, company, canceled, breakAfter, start_formatted, end_formatted;
      var dataLen = $scope.dateOne[date].length;
    };


    for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i++) {
      start = moment($scope.dateOne[date][i].start, 'H:mm');
      end = moment($scope.dateOne[date][i].end, 'H:mm');
      start_formatted = start.format('h:mm a').replace("am", "a.m.").replace("pm", "p.m.");
      end_formatted = end.format('h:mm a').replace("am", "a.m.").replace("pm", "p.m.");
      company = $scope.dateOne[date][i].company;
      canceled = $scope.dateOne[date][i].canceled;
      breakAfter = $scope.dateOne[date][i].breakAfter;

      $scope.allCompanies.push({
        company: company,
        start_formatted: start_formatted,
        end_formatted: end_formatted,
        canceled: canceled,
        breakAfter
      });

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the problem? What does not work as expected?

Comment: you should provide some more information about your problem. from what i see in your code you have already  an array with the promises that are resolved within the $q.all callback

Comment: As of right now $scope.allCompanies has only data from the roomOne.json, that builds the same <td> in all <th> I would like to take all json and store all its data into $scope.allCompanies and then be able to render all companies in the proper <th>Room Name. Not really sure if this helps =/

Comment: you are overwriting `$scope.dateOne` in each iteration of the `forEach` loop

Comment: also don't use `$scope` to assign everything....only what the view needs. Just use `var` or `let` otherwise. Will make your code easier to follow